# microk8s not running after installation

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, microk8s

I want to install kubeflow using microk8s on kubernetes cluster, but I faced a problem with microk8s. I already install microk8s using this [link](https://microk8s.io/). So, when I tried to see the status on microk8s, it was said not running

```
microk8s is not running. Use microk8s inspect for a deeper inspection.
```

When I try to inspect it, and it was said like this

```
Inspecting Certificates
Inspecting services
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-cluster-agent is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver-kicker is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-k8s-dqlite is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelite is running
  Copy service arguments to the final report tarball
Inspecting AppArmor configuration
Gathering system information
  Copy processes list to the final report tarball
  Copy snap list to the final report tarball
  Copy VM name (or none) to the final report tarball
  Copy disk usage information to the final report tarball
  Copy memory usage information to the final report tarball
  Copy server uptime to the final report tarball
  Copy current linux distribution to the final report tarball
  Copy openSSL information to the final report tarball
  Copy network configuration to the final report tarball
Inspecting kubernetes cluster
  Inspect kubernetes cluster
Inspecting juju
  Inspect Juju
Inspecting kubeflow
  Inspect Kubeflow
Inspecting dqlite
  Inspect dqlite

 WARNING:  IPtables FORWARD policy is DROP. Consider enabling traffic forwarding with: sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT 
The change can be made persistent with: sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
WARNING:  Docker is installed. 
Add the following lines to /etc/docker/daemon.json: 
{
    "insecure-registries" : ["localhost:32000"] 
}
and then restart docker with: sudo systemctl restart docker
Building the report tarball
  Report tarball is at /var/snap/microk8s/2718/inspection-report-20211123_074111.tar.gz
```

Comment: How you installed microk8s, please add information about your system. Have you used any installation guide?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin Yeah sure, I've installed the microk8s, and I use this guide installation [link](https://microk8s.io/). What did you mean about the system ? my ubuntu spec? I used GCP VM with spec 4vCPU and 16 GB with storage 60 GB (Both on Master & Worker node)

Comment: Yes, under the system I mean a description of the system where you try to install microk8s.
Under your link is the main page of microk8s site. I don't see a guide on it. Also from your comment, you want to run microk8s on a master and one worker nodes, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the microk8s service is not running but the microk8s inspect reports that it's running. You can try to reset it using:

```
% sudo microk8s reset
Disabling all addons
Disabling addon : core/cert-manager
Disabling addon : core/dashboard
Disabling addon : core/dns
Disabling addon : core/gpu
Disabling addon : core/helm
Disabling addon : core/helm3
Disabling addon : core/host-access
Disabling addon : core/hostpath-storage
Disabling addon : core/ingress
Disabling addon : core/kube-ovn
Disabling addon : core/mayastor
Disabling addon : core/metallb
Disabling addon : core/metrics-server
Disabling addon : core/minio
Disabling addon : core/observability
Disabling addon : core/prometheus
Disabling addon : core/rbac
Disabling addon : core/registry
Disabling addon : core/storage
All addons are disabled.
Deleting the CNI
Cleaning resources in namespace kube-system
Cleaning resources in namespace kube-public
Cleaning resources in namespace kube-node-lease
Cleaning resources in namespace default
Removing CRDs
Removing PriorityClasses
Removing StorageClasses
Restarting cluster
Stopped.
Setting up the CNI
```

and check the status again:

```
% microk8s status
microk8s is running
```

```
% microk8s kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-node-rj5mf                          1/1     Running   0          108s
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-79568db7f8-2sql5   1/1     Running   0          108s
```